# Show Disabled products in collection

Tags: product, category, collection, product-collection, ce-1.9.0.0

On my category page I am trying to show all it's products, even though they are all disabled.

On the category page I am using:

```
$categoryModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$_category_id  = $_category->getId();

$products = $categoryModel->load($_category_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect(array('id', 'name','etc...'))
->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
```

But my collection is always empty.

I have also tried using:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('status', 2)
```

Without success. If i switch the filter to enabled products with either:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)

->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
```

Then (in any other category where products are enabled) then the collection shows all products.

I have flat catalog turned off/set to No in my configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::getProductCollection()`:

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
        ->addCategoryFilter($this);
    return $collection;
}
```

That `ProductCollection::addCategoryFilter()` call does quite a lot of stuff related to category products display logic, mainly via `ProductCollection::_applyProductLimitations()`.

You can set up a frontend observer to consume the `catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after` event dispatched in `_applyProductLimitations()`. You might need to start with debugging the collection in your observer to get the current SELECT statement which you'll need to bang your logic onto.