# Getting collection programatically won't load out of stock items

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection

I'm trying to load a collection of simple products programmatically. However, for some reason, Magento is filtering out of stock products with

`WHERE (IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = 1)`

Even though I did not use `addInStockFilterToCollection` anywhere in the code! I tried setting `Show Out of stock` products both to true and false, and neither seemed to work..

What might be the reason?

Comment: Please post the actual code you use to summon the collection. I can test it out and see where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`status` is not the stock status but the "Status" attribute (enabled or disabled). As soon as you add a store filter, only products **enabled** within this store are loaded

This question also might help you: [Show Disabled products in collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87309/show-disabled-products-in-collection)

Comment: The products aren't disabled. I've tried to manually debug the query. It seems filtering by category seems to be the reason... Odd since the category is full of products..